# Laptop Touch-pad stops working after reattaching parts

Tags: laptop, touchpad, lcd

I was trying to replace my LCD screen for the first time, and it was a very hard process to do. I had to unscrew everything from the bottom of the laptop (Ram, HD, etc) and detach everything that was under the keyboard. After reattaching the LCD, putting everything back together, the touch-pad has stop working. Everything works except for that.  Anybody know why it stopped working?

I have an [HP G61-429WM](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=hp+G61+laptop&hl=en&rlz=1C1GPCK_enUS397US397&prmd=ivns&resnum=3&biw=1440&bih=787&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=9880833987600878282&sa=X&ei=p2loTfCrDsH3gAfl_9nLCg&ved=0CGkQ8wIwAA#) Laptop.

Sorry if this was the wrong place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're best bet here is to take the laptop apart again and check to make sure the connector for the touch pad is fully and properly connected.  It may just be that the connector pushes in further than you thought.  Connectors for random laptop components are notorious for being somewhat difficult to reconnect by hand (at least in my experience).

Comment: ...and take precautions against static (if it's not too late!)